# How to project value as field in Mongodb Aggregation Framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I project the values in mongodb from it's field. my current projection return result as follow

```
[
  {
    "_id": "preferred",
    "value": 314
  },
  {
    "_id": "standard",
    "value": 7778
  }
]
```

But I would like to get this result as

```
[
  {
    "preferred": 314
  },
  {
    "standard": 7778
  }
]
```

I tried with

```
db.collection.aggregate({...},{$project:{"$_id":"$value"}})
```

but it doesn't work. Is there some easy way? Thank you

Comment: I believe it won't work the way you expect. If there is some way, it's better that I get to know a thing.

Comment: you can't do it.  Vote for this ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947

Answer (score 1):

Do you always know what your _id values will be? If so, something like this worked for me. (untested)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project:{
        preferred:{
            $cond: [ {$eq:["$_id","preferred"]}, "$value", 0 ]
        },
        standard:{
            $cond: [ {$eq:["$_id","standard"]}, "$value", 0 ]
        }
    }
})
```

I have no idea how performant this may or may not be.

Comment: If you put null rather than 0 as the 'else' value - will MongoDB skip that field in the output?